# Node.js synchronous shell exec

Tags: node.js, shell, asynchronous

I am having a problem with async shell executes in node.js.

In my case, node.js is installed on a Linux operating system on a raspberry pi. I want to fill an array with values that are parsed from a shell script which is called on the pi. This works fine, however, the exec() function is called asynchronously.

I need the function to be absolute synchron to avoid messing up my whole system. Is there any way to achieve this? Currently I am trying a lib called .exe, but the code still seems to behave asynchron.

Here's my code:

```
function execute(cmd, cb)
{
  child = exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr)
  {
    cb(stdout, stderr);
  });
}



function chooseGroup()
{
  var groups = [];

  execute("bash /home/pi/scripts/group_show.sh", function(stdout, stderr)
  {
    groups_str  = stdout;
    groups      = groups_str.split("\n");
  });

  return groups;
}


//Test
console.log(chooseGroup());
```

Comment: Your question is still unclear.  You reference synchronous in some places and asynchronous in others and it is unclear what problem you are trying to solve or how you want the desired solution to behave.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're using is [child_process.exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), it is asynchronous already.

Your `chooseGroup()` function will not work properly because it is asynchronous.  The `groups` variable will always be empty.

Your `chooseGroup()` function can work if you change it like this:

```
function chooseGroup() {    
  execute("bash /home/pi/scripts/group_show.sh", function(stdout, stderr) {
    var groups = stdout.split("\n");
    // put the code here that uses groups
    console.log(groups);
  });
}

// you cannot use groups here because the result is obtained asynchronously
// and thus is not yet available here.
```

If, for some reason, you're looking for a synchronous version of `.exec()`, there is `child_process.execSync()` though it is rarely recommended in server-based code because it is blocking and thus blocks execution of other things in node.js while it is running.